List of components not rendered correctly after deleting one child
I've a list of objects that are loaded into a for-loop of child components. For each child, there is a button that allow me to remove the selected child.
The deleted child is deleted correctly from the list but, when rendered, only the last child is removed.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Here is an example :

The result :

Here is the code from the parent :
<tbody>
  <route-form-row
    v-for="(route, index) in form.current_routes"
    :key="index"
    :organizations="organizations"
    :route="route"
    :index="index"
    :completed="form.completed"
    @onUpdateOrganization="updateCurrentRouteOrganization"
    @onUpdateNumberOfRoutes="updateCurrentRouteNumberOfRoutes"
    @onRemoveRoute="removeCurrentRoute"
  ></route-form-row>
</tbody>

Here is how I remove the child item:
removeCurrentRoute(index) {
  this.form.current_routes.splice(index, 1);
}

Here is the child component:
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select v-model="organization" :class="['form-select', {'is-invalid': organizationError}]" @change.prevent="updateOrganization()">
        <option value="">------</option>
        <option v-for="org in organizations" :key="org.id" :value="org" :selected="organization.id === org.id">{{ org.name }}</option>
      </select>
      <div v-for="error of this.v$.organization.$errors" :key="error.$uid" :class="[{'invalid-feedback': organizationError}]">{{ error.$message }}</div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-2">
      <input type="number" v-model="number_of_routes" :class="['form-control', {'is-invalid': numberOfRoutesError}]" step="1" min="0" @keyup="updateNumberOfRoutes">
      <div v-for="error of this.v$.number_of_routes.$errors" :key="error.$uid" :class="[{'invalid-feedback': numberOfRoutesError}]">{{ error.$message }}</div>
    </td>
    <td class="text-end">
      <div>
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="removeRoute()">
          <font-awesome-icon :icon="['far', 'trash-can']" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
import { useVuelidate } from '@vuelidate/core'
import { requiredIf, helpers, minValue } from "@vuelidate/validators"

export default {
  name: 'RouteFormRow',
  props: {
    index: Number,
    route: Object,
    organizations: Array,
    completed: Boolean
  },
  setup() {
    return { v$: useVuelidate() };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      organization: this.route.organization,
      number_of_routes: this.route.number_of_routes,
    }
  },
  validations() {
    return {
      organization: { required: helpers.withMessage('Ce champ est obligatoire', requiredIf(this.completed)) },
      number_of_routes: {
        required: helpers.withMessage('Ce champ est obligatoire', requiredIf(this.completed)),
        minValue: helpers.withMessage('Assurez-vous que cette valeur est supérieure ou égale à 0.', minValue(0)),
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    organizationError () {return this.v$.organization.$errors.length > 0},
    numberOfRoutesError () {return this.v$.number_of_routes.$errors.length > 0},
  },
  methods: {
    updateOrganization() {
      this.$emit('onUpdateOrganization', this.index, this.organization);
    },
    updateNumberOfRoutes() {
      this.$emit('onUpdateNumberOfRoutes', this.index, this.number_of_routes)
    },
    removeRoute() {
      this.$emit('onRemoveRoute', this.index);
    }
  }
}
</script>

Here is the result when data is loaded and after I clicked on "delete" :


Inspect a little more: check the received index and use the Vue devtools to look at your collection.

You shouldn't use index as a key, unless you know you need it. What you see is the exact result of how this would work. Data (current_routes) is supposed to have ids. It's unclear from what you posted if this is the case. If it doesn't, create temporary ids to identify it. Please, update the question with relevant details regarding the origin of data and the existence of ids

@EstusFlask I don't have other choice to use the index. I cannot use the id of the item because when I add a new item, there is no id.

@kissu the index received is the right one. For example, if I click on the third item (index = 2), the third item if removed from the list. But for some unexplained reason, the last item is removed (not in the list, only from the HTML).

@Kornikopic You can create any unique id, e.g. uuid. But yes, key="route" as you tried will work too

I found the problem.
As @EstusFlask mentioned, I should not use the index as key.
After further investigation, I replaced :key="index" with :key="route".
Now it works fine.

Try to use ESlint to help yourself in the future with common mistakes. Feel also free to accept your own answer when you can.
